# Maximize Spark JDBC read throughput

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a Spark job that basically reads some data from a JDBC source and saves it to Hive. The source can support 100 connections, but no more. If I write something like that:

```scala
val parts_par = parts.par
parts.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(100))
parts.foreach { part =>
    spark
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option(...)
      .option("query", ...)
      .load()
      .write()
      .mode("append")
      .partitionBy("somecolumn")
      .format("hive")
      .saveAtTable(...)
}
```

and run this job on M executors with N cores where M*N==100, then the number of active sessions on the JDBC source is less than 100, presumably because the sessions are busy writing the data to Hive. If I increase the size of the ForkJoinPool and M*N to a number that is greater than 100, then tasks start failing, because they fail to connect to the JDBC source, and take the executors down with them.

Is there a way to somehow split the task in two? To have exactly 100 tasks that only read the data from the JDBC source non-stop and 100 tasks that only write the data into Hive?

Comment: Does queries inside forEach are quering the same table?

Comment: Yes, they are querying the same table, each one accesses its own partition.